# How do SQLAlchemy Connections relate to Session-based transactions?

Tags: python, postgresql, sqlalchemy, zope

I am currently working on a new web application that needs to execute an SQL statement before giving a session to the application itself.

In detail: I am running a PostgreSQL database server with multiple schemas and I need to execute a `SET search_path` statement before the application uses the session. I am also using the `ZopeTransactionExtension` to have transactions automatically handled at the request level.

To ensure the exectuion of the SQL statement, there seem to be two possible ways:

- Executing the statement at the Engine/Connection level via SQLAlchemy events (from [Multi-tenancy with SQLAlchemy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13372001/multi-tenancy-with-sqlalchemy))
- Executing the statement at the session level (from [SQLAlchemy support of Postgres Schemas](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9298296/sqlalchemy-support-of-postgres-schemas))

Since I am using a scoped session and want to keep my transactions intact, I wonder which of these ways will possibly disturb transaction management.

For example, does the Engine hand out a new connection from the Pool on *every query*? Or is it *attached to the session* for its lifetime, i.e. until the request has been processed and the session & transaction are closed/committed?

On the other hand, since I am using a scoped session, can I perform it the way zzzeek suggested it in the second link? That is, is the context preserved and automatically reset once the transaction is over?

Is there possibly a third way that I am missing?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> For example, does the Engine hand out a new connection from the Pool on every query?

only if you have autocommit=True, which should not be the case.

> Or is it attached to the session for its lifetime, i.e. until the request has been processed and the session & transaction are closed/committed?

it's attached per transaction.  But the "search_path" in Postgresql is per postgresql session (not to be confused with SQLAlchemy session) - its basically the lifespan of the connection itself.

The session (and the engine, and the pool) these days has a ton of event hooks you can grab onto in order to set up state like this.  If you want to stick with the Session you can try [after_begin](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/rel_0_8/orm/events.html#sqlalchemy.orm.events.SessionEvents.after_begin).

Comment: Awesome, thank you. Then I will hook into the session. What would be the opposite event? `after_commit`? Because I would want to reset the search_path after the session is finished.