# Modfying ForeignKeyConstraint schema in Alembic post process

Tags: python-3.x, sqlalchemy, alembic

I'm using [process_revision_directives](https://alembic.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/api/runtime.html#alembic.runtime.environment.EnvironmentContext.configure.params.process_revision_directives) to apply some post-processing of the operations generated against a reference schema. The one I'm stuck on is removing the postgres schema from the instructions, so it can be generically changed at runtime using the answer from [another question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44929128/950099).

The below code correctly removes the schema from operations except for `ForeignKeyConstraints` in a `CreateTableOp`.

```
def process_foreign_key(col: sa.ForeignKeyConstraint):
    col.referred_table.schema = None  # Doesn't work


def process_revision_directives(context, revision, directives):
    # Remove the schema from the generated operations
    for op in chain(directives[0].upgrade_ops.ops, directives[0].downgrade_ops.ops):
        if isinstance(op, ops.CreateTableOp):
            op.columns = [
                process_foreign_key(col) if isinstance(col, sa.ForeignKeyConstraint) else col
                for col in op.columns
            ]
        op.schema = None
```

This currently generates output like

```
op.create_table('user',
    sa.Column('id', sa.Integer, nullable=False),
    sa.ForeignKeyConstraint(['id'], ['reference_schema.group.id'], name='group_group_id', onupdate='CASCADE', ondelete='CASCADE'),
)
```

Any ideas on how I should modify these constraint objects to not have `reference_schema.` in the target table?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you look into the rendering chain you can find where the last schema reference is. It's on `op._orig_table`, but the important thing it is on this table twice.

Put the following in your `for` loop.

```py
op._orig_table.schema = None
op._orig_table = op._orig_table.tometadata(clear_meta)
```

where `clear_meta` is a `MetaData` object with no schema, such as

```py
clear_meta = sa.MetaData(bind=session.connection(), schema=None)
```