# How can I use multiple postgres schemas with SQLAlchemy and Alembic

Tags: postgresql, sqlalchemy, orm, schema, alembic

We have a postgres database with two schemas one for dev and one for prod. So we would like to migrate changes from our sqlalchemy orm first to dev, test it and then migrate them to prod.
But Albemic is not really working with this.

I started by just changing the SCHEMA in my sqlalchemy orm file. This works well for one schema. (Except for that it creates a huge commit everytime even though I only add or delete a column. The Commit is huge because it always drops all the constraints and adds them right away. Is there some way to deactivate this? This is not a huge Problem but the commit is practically unreadable because of this)
But if I then change the schema in the ORM file my and run albemic upgrade head again the tables do get correctly created in the second schema but there is not albemic_versions file. So all the changes I then do in the first schema and then try to also do on the second one lead to errors such as
Database not up to date.

I also tried the approach in the DOCS: https://alembic.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/cookbook.html#rudimental-schema-level-multi-tenancy-for-postgresql-databases
So I also removed the SCHEMA from my table definitions but then it didn't create any tables since it got the error can't find Table None.MyTable (Since apparently there is no schema defined or whatever)

Trying the changes from this here [Alembic support for multiple Postgres schemas](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21109218/alembic-support-for-multiple-postgres-schemas)
Lead to albemic again working in Schemas it wasn't supposed to touch.
I would appreciate any help.

My env.py file

```
from logging.config import fileConfig

from sqlalchemy import engine_from_config
from sqlalchemy import pool
from alembic import context
import sys
sys.path.append('..\\model')
from model.model import metadata, SCHEMA




# this is the Alembic Config object, which provides
# access to the values within the .ini file in use.
config = context.config

# Interpret the config file for Python logging.
# This line sets up loggers basically.
if config.config_file_name is not None:
    fileConfig(config.config_file_name)

# add your model's MetaData object here
# for 'autogenerate' support
# from myapp import mymodel
# target_metadata = mymodel.Base.metadata
target_metadata = metadata

# other values from the config, defined by the needs of env.py,
# can be acquired:
# my_important_option = config.get_main_option("my_important_option")
# ... etc.


def run_migrations_offline() -> None:
    """Run migrations in 'offline' mode.

    This configures the context with just a URL
    and not an Engine, though an Engine is acceptable
    here as well.  By skipping the Engine creation
    we don't even need a DBAPI to be available.

    Calls to context.execute() here emit the given string to the
    script output.

    """
    url = config.get_main_option("sqlalchemy.url")
    context.configure(
        url=url,
        target_metadata=target_metadata,
        literal_binds=True,
        dialect_opts={"paramstyle": "named"},
    )

    with context.begin_transaction():
        context.run_migrations()


def run_migrations_online():
    connectable = engine_from_config(
        config.get_section(config.config_ini_section),
        prefix="sqlalchemy.",
        poolclass=pool.NullPool,
        future=True
    )

    current_tenant = context.get_x_argument(as_dictionary=True).get("tenant")
    with connectable.connect() as connection:
        connection.dialect.default_schema_name = current_tenant

        context.configure(
            connection=connection,
            target_metadata=target_metadata,
        )

        with context.begin_transaction():
            context.run_migrations()


if context.is_offline_mode():
    run_migrations_offline()
else:
    run_migrations_online()
```

A Class definition from orm

```
SCHEMA = 'my_scheme'
metadata = MetaData(schema=SCHEMA)
Base = declarative_base(metadata=metadata)


class CertScheme(Base):
    __table_args__ = {'schema': SCHEMA}
    __tablename__ = 'CertScheme'

    id = Column(BigInteger, primary_key=True)
    name = Column(String(20), nullable=False)
    company = Column(String(70))
    company_url = Column(String(100))
    description = Column(Text)
```

Answer (score 0):

This configuration did what I wanted

```
import os
from logging.config import fileConfig

from sqlalchemy import engine_from_config
from sqlalchemy import pool

from alembic import context

# this is the Alembic Config object, which provides
# access to the values within the .ini file in use.
config = context.config

# Interpret the config file for Python logging.
# This line sets up loggers basically.
if config.config_file_name is not None:
    fileConfig(config.config_file_name)

# add your model's MetaData object here
# for 'autogenerate' support
# from myapp import mymodel
# target_metadata = mymodel.Base.metadata
import sys
sys.path.append('..\\model')
from model.model import metadata, SCHEMA

target_metadata = metadata

# other values from the config, defined by the needs of env.py,
# can be acquired:
# my_important_option = config.get_main_option("my_important_option")
# ... etc.

db_name = config.config_ini_section # active config ini section is the db name that we have chosen
config.set_main_option(
    "sqlalchemy.url",
    f'YOUR DATABASE URL'
)


def run_migrations_offline() -> None:
    """Run migrations in 'offline' mode.

    This configures the context with just a URL
    and not an Engine, though an Engine is acceptable
    here as well.  By skipping the Engine creation
    we don't even need a DBAPI to be available.

    Calls to context.execute() here emit the given string to the
    script output.

    """
    url = config.get_main_option("sqlalchemy.url")
    context.configure(
        url=url,
        target_metadata=target_metadata,
        literal_binds=True,
        dialect_opts={"paramstyle": "named"},
    )

    with context.begin_transaction():
        context.run_migrations()


def run_migrations_online() -> None:
    """Run migrations in 'online' mode.

    In this scenario we need to create an Engine
    and associate a connection with the context.

    """
    connectable = engine_from_config(
        config.get_section(config.config_ini_section),
        prefix="sqlalchemy.",
        poolclass=pool.NullPool,
    )

    def include_object(object, name, type_, reflected, compare_to):
        if type_ == "table" and object.schema != SCHEMA:
            return False
        else:
            return True

    with connectable.connect() as connection:
        context.configure(
            connection=connection, target_metadata=target_metadata, include_object=include_object, include_schemas=True, version_table_schema=SCHEMA
        )

        with context.begin_transaction():
            context.run_migrations()


if context.is_offline_mode():
    run_migrations_offline()
else:
    run_migrations_online()
```

And the alembic.ini file

```
    # A generic, single database configuration.

[alembic]
# path to migration scripts
databases = ism_a, ism_b


[DEFAULT]
# template used to generate migration files


# template used to generate migration file names; The default value is %%(rev)s_%%(slug)s
# Uncomment the line below if you want the files to be prepended with date and time
# see https://alembic.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/tutorial.html#editing-the-ini-file
# for all available tokens
file_template = %%(year)d_%%(month).2d_%%(day).2d_%%(hour).2d%%(minute).2d-%%(rev)s_%%(slug)s

# sys.path path, will be prepended to sys.path if present.
# defaults to the current working directory.
prepend_sys_path = .
script_location = ./alembic/
# timezone to use when rendering the date within the migration file
# as well as the filename.
# If specified, requires the python-dateutil library that can be
# installed by adding `alembic[tz]` to the pip requirements
# string value is passed to dateutil.tz.gettz()
# leave blank for localtime
# timezone =

# max length of characters to apply to the
# "slug" field


# set to 'true' to run the environment during
# the 'revision' command, regardless of autogenerate
# revision_environment = false

# set to 'true' to allow .pyc and .pyo files without
# a source .py file to be detected as revisions in the
# versions/ directory
# sourceless = false

# version location specification; This defaults
# to alembic/versions.  When using multiple version
# directories, initial revisions must be specified with --version-path.
# The path separator used here should be the separator specified by "version_path_separator" below.
# version_locations = %(here)s/bar:%(here)s/bat:alembic/versions

# version path separator; As mentioned above, this is the character used to split
# version_locations. The default within new alembic.ini files is "os", which uses os.pathsep.
# If this key is omitted entirely, it falls back to the legacy behavior of splitting on spaces and/or commas.
# Valid values for version_path_separator are:
#
# version_path_separator = :
# version_path_separator = ;
# version_path_separator = space
version_path_separator = os

# the output encoding used when revision files
# are written from script.py.mako
# output_encoding = utf-8

sqlalchemy.url = driver://user:pass@localhost/dbname

[ism_a]
sqlalchemy.url = driver://user:pass@localhost/dbname
version_locations = ./alembic/versions/ism_a

[ism_b]
sqlalchemy.url = driver://user:pass@localhost/dbname
version_locations = ./alembic/versions/ism_b



[post_write_hooks]
# post_write_hooks defines scripts or Python functions that are run
# on newly generated revision scripts.  See the documentation for further
# detail and examples

# format using "black" - use the console_scripts runner, against the "black" entrypoint
# hooks = black
# black.type = console_scripts
# black.entrypoint = black
# black.options = -l 79 REVISION_SCRIPT_FILENAME

# Logging configuration
[loggers]
keys = root,sqlalchemy,alembic

[handlers]
keys = console

[formatters]
keys = generic

[logger_root]
level = WARN
handlers = console
qualname =

[logger_sqlalchemy]
level = WARN
handlers =
qualname = sqlalchemy.engine

[logger_alembic]
level = INFO
handlers =
qualname = alembic

[handler_console]
class = StreamHandler
args = (sys.stderr,)
level = NOTSET
formatter = generic

[formatter_generic]
format = %(levelname)-5.5s [%(name)s] %(message)s
datefmt = %H:%M:%S
```