# Doing multi-tenancy in Websauna

Tags: websauna

My approach to develop a multi-tenant i.e. Shared Database, Separate Schemas ideally on PostgreSQL. One database for all tenants, but one schema per tenant similar to [django tenant schemas](https://django-tenant-schemas.readthedocs.io/en/latest/). Is there a guide or addon to achieve this on websauna?

Answer (score 2):

Here is what there is and there isn't

Already there

- [SQLAlchemy supports PostgreSQL tenancy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9298296/sqlalchemy-support-of-postgres-schemas). You can set this by overriding the database session factory when subclassing `websauna.system.Initializer` for your application. See [configure_database](https://websauna.org/docs/api/websauna.system.html?highlight=configure_database#websauna.system.Initializer.configure_database) that leads you to the path that allows to override [create_dbsession](https://websauna.org/docs/api/websauna.system.model.meta.html?highlight=create_dbsession#websauna.system.model.meta.create_dbsession). Your database session factory would look the properties of the HTTP request (domain) and configure session to point to the corresponding schema accordingly.
- Add-on architecture that could provide a pluggable `websauna.tenant` addon
- Theming: CSS and other assets (logo) can be customized by providing a `site/base.html` template that is a tenant aware. E.g. it injects `css.html` in `<head>` with the ability to define CSS filenames from the database. You would override the default `site/base.html` in the `websauna.tenant` addon.

Missing

- Alembic  migration supports PSQL schemas, but not sure how complete this support is
- There isn't `Tenant` model e.g. [to track the subscriber billing status](https://django-tenant-schemas.readthedocs.io/en/latest/install.html#the-tenant-model)

Comment: Alembic has some support for schmas: http://alembic.zzzcomputing.com/en/latest/ops.html?highlight=schema#alembic.operations.Operations.create_table.params.schema