# Pandas to_sql doesn't insert any data in my table

Tags: python, pandas, sqlalchemy

I am trying to insert some data in a table I have created.
I have a data frame that looks like this:

[image: dataframe]

I created a table:

```
create table online.ds_attribution_probabilities
(
attribution_type text,
channel text,
date date ,
value float
)
```

And I am running this python script:

```
engine = create_engine("postgresql://@e.eu-central-1.redshift.amazonaws.com:5439/mdhclient_encoding=utf8")
connection = engine.raw_connection()
result.to_sql('online.ds_attribution_probabilities', con=engine, index = False, if_exists = 'append')
```

I get no error, but when I check there are no data in my table. What can be wrong? Do I have to commit or do an extra step?

Answer (score 60, accepted):

Try to specify a schema name:

```
result.to_sql('ds_attribution_probabilities', con=engine, 
              schema='online', index=False, if_exists='append')
```

Comment: got me stuck as well.  Thanks!

Comment: A clear bug, as for me. Not only it makes no sense, but it fails silently: 3 years passed, and it's still unsolved lurking there, waiting for the next prey...

Comment: I believe the table is created on the postgres `public` schema when the schema parameter is not passed, hence it is not 'silently failing' rather creating the table in a place where you don't expect.

Comment: 1+ or if you've already included the schema in the DB connection, don't put it in the table name.

Comment: If it is not bug, it is poor design

Comment: no my to_sql still inserts nothing into my mariadb even i have included schema, and index parameter into my syntax.

Answer (score 19):

Hopefully this helps someone else. `to_sql` will fail silently in the form of what looks like a successful insert if you pass a connection object. This is definitely true for Postgres, but i assume the same for others as well, based on the method docs:

```
con : sqlalchemy.engine.Engine or sqlite3.Connection
    Using SQLAlchemy makes it possible to use any DB supported by that
    library. Legacy support is provided for sqlite3.Connection objects.
```

This got me because the typing hints stated `Union[Engine, Connection]`, which is "technically" true.

If you have a session with `SQLAlchemy` try passing `con=session.get_bind(),`

Comment: OMG, that was my problem! I cannot believe that is actually the current behavior o_O

Comment: Whats worse is that if its failing silently due to an unspecified explicit schema passed as an argument, it creates the table in your publiv schema! Thats where all your disappearing data is being appended to!

Comment: beware the "silent fail" when using `engine.connect()` for the `to_sql` `con` param! So much time wasted debugging, would like for this to be addressed

Answer (score 16):

I had a similar issue caused by the fact that I was passing sqlalchemy *connection* object instead of *engine* object to the *con* parameter. In my case tables were created but left empty.

Comment: Worked for me 

`self.engine = create_engine(f'mysql+pymysql://{self.db_user}:{self.db_password}@{self.db_host}:{self.db_port}/{self.db_name}')

with self.engine.connect() as conn:
                result = df.to_sql('table-name', self.engine, if_exists='append', index=False)`

earlier I was passing conn instead of engine obj

Comment: I don't understand, all the other answer doesn't work, including this https://stackoverflow.com/a/48307108/9779999, but this specific one right above my comment ( by Ravi Bhanushali
 Feb 21 at 14:57 ) works perfectly. If yours is not in a Class function just feel free to remove the "self.".

Answer (score 3):

In my case, writing data to the database was hampered by the fast option.

Why is this not fast loading interfering, I have not yet figured out.

This code doesn't work:

```
engine = sqlalchemy.create_engine("mssql+pyodbc:///?odbc_connect={}".format(db_params), fast_executemany=True)
df.to_sql('tablename', engine, index=False, schema = 'dbo', if_exists='replace' )
```

Without `fast_executemany=True` the code works well.

Answer (score 2):

Check the `autocommit` setting: https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/core/connections.html#understanding-autocommit

```
engine.execute(text("SELECT my_mutating_procedure()").execution_options(autocommit=True))
```

Answer (score 1):

I faced the same problem when I used `.connect()` and `.begin()`

```
with engine.connect() as conn, conn.begin():
         dataframe.to_sql(name='table_name', schema='schema',
         con=conn, if_exists='append', index=False)
         conn.close()
```

Just remove the `.connect()` and `.begin()` and it will work.

Comment: Isn't the whole point of a context manager is you don't have to call close() or begin()?

Answer (score 1):

This could happen because it defaults to the public database, and there's probably a table with that name under the public database/schema, with your data in it.

@MaxU's answer does help some, but not the others.
For others, here is something else you can try:

When you create the engine, specify the schemaname like this:

```
engine = create_engine(*<connection_string>*,
    connect_args={'options': '-csearch_path={}'.format(*<dbschema_name>*)})
```

Link: https://stackoverflow.com/a/49930672/8656608

Answer (score 0):

use `method=None`

> None : Uses standard SQL INSERT clause (one per row).

https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.to_sql.html

Mine worked like this:

```
df.to_sql(name=table_name, method=None, schema=schema, index=False, if_exists='append', chunksize=50, con=conn.get_bind())
```

****table_name** without prepending the schema name*

Answer (score 0):

Try adding commit after you code, like this:

```
result.to_sql('ds_attribution_probabilities', con=engine, 
          schema='online', index=False, if_exists='append')
engine.commit()
```

Works for me.

Comment: Answer needs supporting information
Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/76226167/edit) to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: I don't think you can engine.commit(), it would be connection.commit().

Answer (score 0):

5 Years later faced the same issue with PostgreSQL.

I solved it by passing the actual connection object instead of the engine itself (which I did previously).

```
engine = create_engine('postgresql://username:password@localhost:5432/database_name')
with engine.connect() as connection:
     dataset.to_sql(name='table_name', con=connection, schema='schema_name', if_exists='append', chunksize=1000, index=False)
```

Previously I was doing

```
engine = create_engine('postgresql://username:password@localhost:5432/database_name')
dataset.to_sql(name='table_name', con=engine, schema='schema_name', if_exists='append', chunksize=1000, index=False)
```

As you may have noticed above that I have passed the `schema_name` too. I did that after I saw the responses above. But that did not solve the issue.

While the table was created in the DB, no records were written into it. I found it pretty strange due to this last bit. I could have fully understood if the table itself wasn't getting created and I would have concluded that Python is failing to establish a database connection altogether.

Answer (score 0):

Check that you are passing in the database to `create_engine`

for postgres, it will be something like this

```
engine = create_engine(f'postgresql://{DB_USER}:{DB_PASS}@{DB_HOST}:{DB_PORT}/{DB_NAME}')
```