# Not able to insert data in AWS postgres RDS

Tags: python, postgresql, amazon-web-services, sqlalchemy, amazon-rds

I am unable to add pandas dataframe in aws postgres through pandas to_sql

I have tried adding one by one record and it works properly but when i try to add dataframe it doesn't shows any error and it is not committed

```
import pandas as pd 

import sqlalchemy
from sqlalchemy import create_engine
from sqlalchemy.orm import sessionmaker

host="####.amazonaws.com"
port=5432
dbname="@@@@"
user="@@@@"
password="&&&&"

engine=create_engine("@@@@://@@@@:&&&&@####.amazonaws.com:5432/@@@@",
                       echo = True)

pd.read_sql("select * from Cities", engine)
```

id  cityname    latitude    longitude

0   1   New York City   40.73   -73.93

1   100 abcdef  12.33   14.11

2   100 abcdef  -12.33  14.11

```
tempdf = {'id': 1000, 'cityname': 'Delhi', 'latitude': '120', 'longitude': '110'}

tempdf = pd.DataFrame(list(tempdf.items()))

tempdf.to_sql(name='Cities', con=engine, index=False, if_exists='append')

pd.read_sql("select * from Cities", engine)
```

id  cityname    latitude    longitude

0   1   New York City   40.73   -73.93

1   100 abcdef  12.33   14.11

2   100 abcdef  -12.33  14.11

Answer (score 0):

Answer linked below appears to suggest adding schema argument to your `to_sql` statement:

[Pandas to_sql doesn't insert any data in my table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48307008/pandas-to-sql-doesnt-insert-any-data-in-my-table?noredirect=1&lq=1)