# To_sql fails to update mysql table

Tags: python, mysql, pandas, sqlalchemy

I am trying to insert a dataframe to a table in mysql:

```
sql = """
select MakeID, MakeName brand  FROM Makes m
"""
sql_d = pd.read_sql(sql, conn)

mycursor = mydb.cursor()
mycursor.execute('create table Brand (id int auto_increment primary Key, MakeId int(10), brand varchar(100))')

from sqlalchemy import create_engine

engine = create_engine('mysql+pymysql://user:password@host/database')

sql_d.to_sql(name='Brand', con= engine, method= None,if_exists= 'replace', index= False)
```

The code runs successfully without errors but when I check the Brand table, no data is updated. I searched and found this issue in [Pandas to_sql doesn't insert any data in my table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48307008/pandas-to-sql-doesnt-insert-any-data-in-my-table). I also tried but did not work. what should I do?

Answer (score 0):

Try this code which resolves some potential issues.

- You haven't specified the conn variable.
- You need to commit the create table query before adding in the data.
- Ambiguous column names, column names in DF must match to SQL column names.
- You can't specify int(10) it must just be int.
- I would suggest not having a column name and table name the same.

```
from sqlalchemy import create_engine

engine = create_engine('mysql+pymysql://user:password@host/database')
conn = engine.raw_connection()
mycursor= conn.cursor()

sql = """
select [MakeID], [brand] FROM [Makes]
"""
sql_d = pd.read_sql(sql, conn)

mycursor.execute("""
                    Create Table [Brand_Table] (
                        id int auto_increment primary Key, 
                        MakeId int, 
                        brand varchar(100)
                        )     
                 """)
conn.commit()
conn.close()

sql_d.to_sql(name="Brand_Table", con=engine, index=False, if_exists='append', method=None)
```

Comment: `if_exists='replace'` makes the `create table` statement useless since `.to_sql()` will replace it anyway

Comment: Yes that's true it should be append, I will edit. Thank You