# Flask-Sqlalchemy Acess different schema?

Tags: python, flask, sqlalchemy, flask-sqlalchemy

Say I have a Postgres database with two different schema's, one called `public` and one called `development`.  I know at the class level I can set `__table_args__ = {"schema":"schema_name"}` for each model, but if I wanted to switch from development to prod. wouldn't I haven't to update all my models?

Is there a way to set the schema for the dev and prod schemas in flask? Or should I just create another database as a dev database and just backup the prod database to the development database?

Comment: Have you read https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9298296/sqlalchemy-support-of-postgres-schemas? It probably isn't the answer, but it has something in common.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming there's something in the config along the lines of PRODUCTION = False/True, then you should be able to set the schema by adding into the models:

```
if app.config['PRODUCTION']:
    db_schema = 'public'
else:
    db_schema = 'development'
```

And then update your table_args:

```
__table_args__ = {'schema': db_schema }
```