# Postgres sqlalchemy Session creation with schema name

Tags: python, postgresql, sqlalchemy, typeerror

I can able to create postgres sqlalchemy connection to 'public' schema.

```
 url = 'postgresql://scott:tiger@localhost:5432/mydatabase'
 engine = create_engine(url)
 engine.connect()
 session = sessionmaker(bind=engine)
 Session = session()
```

Now try to connect non-public schema say 'myschema'.

```
 engine = create_engine(url, connect_args={"schema" : "myschema"})
 engine.connect()
 session = sessionmaker(bind=engine)
 Session = session()
```

I got error :

```
TypeError: connect() got an unexpected keyword argument 'schema'
```

How can i connect postgres by using able statements.

Thank you.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/49930672/4134674

Comment: This seems really ugly/complex... there's no simpler way to just tell sqlalchemy (don't use public use "foo")?

Answer (score 1):

This is valid connection string for specific schema:

```
engine = create_engine('postgresql://dbuser:dbpass@localhost:5432/dbname', connect_args={'options': '-csearch_path={}'.format('dbschema')})
```