# Dynamically change the schema name in _table_args_ in flask

Tags: python, postgresql, sqlalchemy, flask-sqlalchemy

In a flask application, I have a user table in multiple schemas. I can list the users inside a schema by specifying the schema in the model using `__table_args__`

```
class User(db.Model):
    __table_args__ = {"schema": "schema1"} #fetch the user table in "schema1" schema
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    timestamp = db.Column(db.DateTime, index=True, default=datetime.utcnow)
    name = db.Column(db.String)
```

But I have no idea to change the schema name dynamically. How to change the schema name by passing a string from the controller?

Comment: Which DBMS are you using?

Comment: using postgresql

Comment: Maybe instead of tying your model to the schema and then having to change that, alter your search path: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9298296/sqlalchemy-support-of-postgres-schemas