# Multi-tenant with Postgres schemas and SQLAlchemy ORM - connection, session and options sanity

Tags: python-3.x, postgresql, sqlalchemy, multi-tenant

In a multi-tenant application, I would like to make use of [PostgreSQL schemas](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9298296/sqlalchemy-support-of-postgres-schemas) with SQLAlchemy 1.3.

It seems convenient from a SQL perspective: table names are simply to be prefixed with the schema name to achieve tenant isolation, eg `customer` becomes `tenant1.customer`.

How does that translate in SQLAlchemy?

I do a `sessionmaker` once [as per the documentation](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/13/orm/session_basics.html#when-do-i-make-a-sessionmaker), during application startup. Connections can be pooled. The DB URL is the "root" of the database so that I can "see" all schemas and switch dynamically, on a per query basis:

```
engine = create_engine(database_url)
session_factory = sessionmaker(bind=self.engine)
```

To achieve scoping on a schema, I found a hint to set `execution_options` with `schema_translate_map` [on the connection](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56490246/1215723), like so:

```
session.connection(execution_options={
    "schema_translate_map": {"per_user": "account_one"}})

# will query from the ``account_one.user`` table
session.query(User).get(5)
```

It seems to work, but is there any risk of **side effect**, **race condition** or otherwise **connection pollution** (when the connection is returned to the pool) if I modify the `connection` on the `session`? The example I found in the [official documentation](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/13/core/connections.html#schema-translating) sets the `execution_options` earlier, on `engine.connect()`, so I am unsure if we are talking about the same thing.

Another suggestion is to [set the search path](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9299021/1215723) with `SET search_path` but I keep it as a last resort, as it taints the connection, unless you reset the search path to its original value afterwards. Also it does not look good from a performance perspective, and it seems clumsy at best - as opposed to simply prefixing table name with the schema name.

Finally, in version 1.4, there is a [new](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/14/orm/query.html#sqlalchemy.orm.Query.execution_options) `Query.execution_options` that looks like a good option but it is still a beta release so I cannot rely on that yet for production.

Any advice on the sanity of the proposed options? Does the 1.4 construct change the game?

Comment: Hi @youri, any update on this?

Comment: No progress made on the task @yeger. We may stick to the current architecture, eg one code deployment and one database per tenant. It has its drawbacks in terms of devops but you get perfect isolation without any legacy code change. Still reluctant to go down the path I suggested - it seems to be the path less traveled.