# Why doesn't SQLAlchemy reflect tables in non-public schema?

Tags: postgresql, reflection, sqlalchemy

I have a PostgreSQL database, which has had all objects in public schema.
Used SQLAlchemy to succesfully connect to it and reflect objects from it.

Now I needed to create a separate schema *schema2* in the same database. I assigned to new user all rights in that schema, checked that I can connect from command line with psql and do things in it.

But SQLAlchemy doesn't see any tables in the schema, when I try to use the same method to reflect its tables -- despite trying various ways to specify schema!

This is what worked for initial connection to public schema:

```
from sqlalchemy.ext.automap import automap_base
from sqlalchemy import create_engine
from sqlalchemy import Table, Integer, String, Text,  Column, ForeignKey

Base=automap_base()
sql_conn='postgres://my_user@/foo'
engine=create_engine(sql_conn)

Base.prepare(engine, reflect=True)
```

Then I could use Base.classes.* for tables and I didn't need to create Table classes on my own.

Now, this same *works* for this new user for *public* schema as well.

But whenever I somehow try to pass the schema2 to reflect tables from schema2, I always get empty Base.classes.*

I tried all the solutions in [SQLAlchemy support of Postgres Schemas](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9298296/sqlalchemy-support-of-postgres-schemas) but I don't get anything at all reflected!

I tried:

- making user's default schema schema2 via SQL means:
  `ALTER new_user SET search_path=schema2;`
- tried to pass schema in engine.connect via engine options
- tried to set schema in MetaData and use that, as per SQLAlchemy docs:

Doing:

```
meta=MetaData(bind=engine,schema='schema2')
meta.reflect()
```

does work, as I can see all the tables correctly in meta.tables afterwards.

However, when I try to get Base.classes working as per [SQLAlchemy automapper docs](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/13/orm/extensions/automap.html), the Base.classes don't get populated:

```
from sqlalchemy.ext.automap import automap_base
from sqlalchemy import create_engine
from sqlalchemy import Table, Integer, String, Text,  Column, ForeignKey, MetaData

sql_conn='postgres://new_user@/foo'
engine=create_engine(sql_conn)
meta=MetaData(bind=engine,schema='schema2') 
Base=automap_base(metadata=meta)
Base.prepare(engine, reflect=True)
```

Base.classes is empty...

I am now stumped. Any ideas?

PS. I am working on newest SQLAlchemy available (1.3) under pip for Python2.7, Ubuntu 18.04LTS.

Comment: I am unable to reproduce your issue. [This code](https://pastebin.com/EsZ2XwZR) works fine for me with SQLAlchemy 1.3.23. Does `new_user` have sufficient permissions on the PostgreSQL server to "see" the tables in the non-public schema?

Comment: @GordThompson Yes, he has. As indicated by that meta.tables *is* being populated:


meta.tables
Out[11]: immutabledict({u'schema2.table1': Table('table1', MetaData(bind=Engine(postgres://new_user@/foo)), Column('order_id', INTEGER(), ForeignKey(u'schema2.table1.id'), table=<table1>, nullable=False), Column('gtin', VARCHAR(length=20), table=<....

Comment: @GordThompson The only difference I see from what you posted, is, I am on Python 2, not 3.

Comment: My test code produces the same results with Python 2.7.17 on Xubuntu 18.04 hitting PostgreSQL 12.3.

Comment: @GordThompson hmm, my postgres is 9.3. I will try to create an empty database and check there.

Comment: If `new_user` does not have Superuser privileges then perhaps try temporarily granting them (or test with some other user that has them) to verify that this is not a permissions issue. Reflection often relies on reading system tables that aren't always available to users without elevated (admin-like) permissions.

Comment: @GordThompson Tried with SUPERUSER. Same happens. meta.tables gets populated with correct information, but not Base.classes .

Comment: PostgreSQL 9.5 is the oldest version currently available from Docker so [this](https://pastebin.com/XxASz4dq) is the closest I can get to your environment version-wise and it works okay for me. (Xubuntu 18.04)