# How to set schema_translate_map in SQLAlchemy object in Flask app

Tags: python, postgresql, flask, sqlalchemy, flask-sqlalchemy

My app.py file

```
from flask import Flask
from flask_sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy

from flask import Flask
from flask_sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy

app = Flask(__name__)
app.config['SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI'] = 'postgres:////tmp/test.db'
db = SQLAlchemy(app) # refer https://flask-sqlalchemy.palletsprojects.com/en/2.x/api/#flask_sqlalchemy.SQLAlchemy
```

One of my model classes, where I imported `db`

```
from app import db
Base = declarative_base()

# User class
class User(db.Model, Base):
  id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
  username = db.Column(db.String(80), unique=True, nullable=False)
  email = db.Column(db.String(120), unique=True, nullable=False)

  def __repr__(self):
    return '<User %r>' % self.username

  def get_user_by_id(self, id):
    return self.query.get(id)
```

My database has the same set of tables in different schema (multi-tenancy) and there
I need to select the schema as per the request initiated by a particular tenant on the fly by using `before_request` (grabbing tenant_id from subdomain URL).

I found Postgres provides selecting the schema name on fly by using
`schema_translate_map` ref. https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/14/core/connections.html#translation-of-schema-names and that is under `execution_options` https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/14/core/connections.html#sqlalchemy.engine.Connection.execution_options

In my above code snippet where you see `db = SQLAlchemy(app)`, as per official documentation, two parameters can be set in `SQLAlchemy` objct creation and they are - `session_options` and `engine_options`, but no `execution_options` ref. https://flask-sqlalchemy.palletsprojects.com/en/2.x/api/#flask_sqlalchemy.SQLAlchemy

But how do I set `schema_translate_map` setting when I am creating an object of `SQLAlchemy`

I tried this -

```
db = SQLAlchemy(app, 
  session_options={
    "autocommit": True, 
    "autoflush": False, 
    "schema_translate_map": {
      None: "public"
    }
  }
)
```

But obviously, it did not work, because `schema_translate_map` is under `execution_options` as mentioned here https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/14/core/connections.html#translation-of-schema-names

Anyone has an idea, how to set `schema_translate_map` at the time of creating `SQLAlchemy` object.

My goal is to set it dynamically for each request. I want to control it from this
centralized place, rather than going in each model file and specifying it when I execute
queries.

I am aware of doing this differently as suggested here https://stackoverflow.com/a/56490246/1560470
but my need is to set somewhere around `db = SQLAlchemy(app)` in `app.py` file only. Then after I import `db` in all my model classes (as shown above) and in those model classes, all queries execute under the selected schema.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I found a way to accomplish it. This is what needed

```py
db = SQLAlchemy(app, 
  session_options={
    "autocommit": True, 
    "autoflush": False
  },
  engine_options={
    "execution_options":
      {
        "schema_translate_map": {
          None: "public",
          "abc": "xyz"
        }
      }
  }
)
```